Adding clauses to a sentence

I didn't arrive because I had broken my leg

Such a sentence after "because" should have past perfect because the leg was broken before "not arriving", but what if I want to add another clause?

I didn't come because I broke my leg when I was walking down the street

What should I do now? Change only first clause to past perfect or both or is my 2 example good on it's own without perfect?
Ps. I know that in reported speech for instance this "I broke my leg when I was walking down the street" would be reported in 3 ways either we don't change tenses or backshift both parts to past perfect or only the part with breaking the leg becomes backshifted. Yet, my examples aren't reported speech

Arrive is an odd verb here. The obvious continuation is I didn't go because I had broken my leg when [I was] walking down the street. Note that you only need to include when because walking down the street isn't a credible reason for breaking a leg. It's not needed in, say, I didn't go because I had broken my leg skiiing. Also note that Past Perfect is unnecessary in such contexts where the sequence of events is obvious: I didn't go because I broke my leg skiiing is fine.

When and how to use the Past Perfect Tense.
OP has asked about Past Perfect usage in the following sentences:


I didn't arrive because I had broken my leg.


Please note:
Past Perfect Tense is used to show that one previous event happened before another in the past..
In many cases, Past Perfect Tense can be avoided.
Suppose I rephrase the sentence:
I didn't come because I broke my leg.
Since there's only one action (breaking the leg), and the other action (arriving) didn't occur, the Past Simple (broke) effectively conveys the reason for not arriving.
The clause "because I broke my leg" is the cause. The main clause "I didn't come" is the result.
Second Sentence


I didn't come because I broke my leg when I was walking down the street.


In the second sentence the added clause "when I was walking down the street" is an adverbial clause and there is no need for establishing a separate timeline.
The sentence  "perfectly" conveys the intended meaning without the Past Perfect Tense.
